# Can't login Ubuntu 18.04 after restart and write commands

Tags: 18.04, login, reboot, tty, unicode

After installing a package and remove it with apt-get, I restarted Ubuntu and can't log in again.

[image: image of my screen in tty console]

When I trying to write in any tty and recovery mode instead of character put square and can't write command correctly.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please write more details how this happened and what package did you remove? and what is the error when you're trying to login?

Comment: install lightdm and remove it after few seconds.

Comment: Asking me username over and over. I think can't recognize my username and putting squares.

Comment: Lightdm is a display manager are you using any other? Do you see a login interface at all?

Comment: No, only install lightdm.

Comment: Yes, I have a login interface but after removing lightdm only have a tty console and can't login correctly.

Comment: You need a display manager to be able to login to desktop environment

Comment: I can't run any command because of command not found in recovery mode.

Comment: login to console and run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop lightdm`

Comment: How to login console when don't recognize my username.

Comment: make sure you write in English, pay attention to Caps Lock etc.

Comment: I check my Caps Lock and still dosn't work. I can't check language. How to change it?

Comment: Usually you can switch it with Alt+Shift

Comment: Dosn't work in tty console for me